# Machine Learning - How to diagnose if my dataset is limiting my results?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, dataset

I am working in a Machine Learning research group on a project related to cancer treatment. My dataset has 149 rows, 19 variables and the dependent variable has 2 possible classes (0 or 1). Also, it is important to notice that exists discrete and continuous features in the dataset.

The problem is that I have tested many different algorithms - such as XGB, Random Forests, Logistic Regression, ANN's - combined with many scaling and variable selection techniques. Nevertheless, none of them is able to get past the barrier of ~73% ROC's AUC, even though for each one of the listed ML algs is possible to get a "best" model with AUC around ~71%.

My hypothesis is that I am probably being limited by my dataset, because, when I plot the scatter plot of the dataset projections onto the 2 most relevant PCA components, some points of different classes almost partly overlap. Therefore, making it impossible even for me to draw by hand a decision boundary.

So, how can I mathematically diagnose if my dataset is limiting my performance?

Answer (score 2):

If getting a larger data set makes your predictions better, then by definition your current data set is limiting your predictions. If you don't have access to more data, you can look at the effect of less data. If you randomly discard some of the rows and redo your analysis on the remaining rows, do your predictions get worse?

> My hypothesis is that I am probably being limited by my dataset, because, when I plot the scatter plot of the dataset projections onto the 2 most relevant PCA components, some points of different classes almost partly overlap.

That doesn't suggest a deficit of data points. In fact, the more data points you get, the more the classes will overlap. This is addressed by including more components, not more data.